# Call tree in JMC 7?

Tags: java, jmc, jfr

Yesterday I've upgrades a project to java 11 because i wanted to give java mission control a try. After a bit of fiddling around i managed to get everything up and running.

While searching the web for info about java mission control i found a few old pages mentioning the "call tree" function (on the "Code" tab) which was present in the closed source version of JMC. This is quite handy to find methods that use a lot of cpu time.

Does anybody know where i can find the "call tree" function in the open sourced version of JMC (JDK Mission Control 7.0.1+b01)?

(or maybe another way to find the cpu usage per method?)

Answer (score 3):

In the "Java Application" section click on "Threads" it will show all the threads used by java process. Select the required thread (Thread-0) and the stack trace is show below with time taken for each method. This is not easy to use as "call tree" feature.